# How to convert shapefile geo-cordinates to a specific location with 3 reference geo-cordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, google-maps

What I have is multi-layer drawing file for a locality in India; with help of a conversion utility got a working Shape-files of it.

Issue is original drawing file is not Geo-coordinated hence Shape file has Geo-coordinates in range of 10 & 13(by default central region); where as for India it should be somewhat 17-18 lat and 72-73 lng.

Now for intended locality I have 3 correct Geo-coordinates on 3 direction of its borders.

Are there any tools/libraries which can help here with using those reference coordinates and convert shape file Geo-coordinates to correct values?

Comment: You could try OGR2OGR https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html with control points, that should warp your shapefile from ungeoreferenced to geolocated position, 3 points is enough to do an affine (first order) transformation. It may not be a good fit if your control points are in a different coordinate reference system to your original.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael; will try out